# How I can buy SLT for gryvna (Ukrainian money)?

Tags: xlm, payments

Is that possible to buy SLT ([SmartLands](https://smartlands.io/) token) for UAH (Ukrainian hryvnas)?

Comment: Hey, what is STL? Is it an asset on the Stellar Network? Also, while this is a completely valid question, it is more suited for the Stellar Slack or possible r/Stellar on Reddit.

Comment: I believe that STL is actually an SLT [SmartLands](https://smartlands.io/) token.

Answer (score 3):

## Brief guide to buying ANY Stellar-based asset

In general the approach looks like the following:

**Fiat** Money (USD, EUR etc.) → **XLM** (Stellar internal currency) → **Asset** of your choice

### 0. Prerequisites

In order to hold XLM and purchase Stellar-based assets, you'll need a Stellar account first. If you don't have one, generate a new account keypair [here](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=public). Securely store and backup your secret key somewhere (preferably on the external drive). Without it you will be unable to login into your account.

### 1. Choose an exchange to convert your fiat money to XLM

**Direct exchange**

Visit [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/stellar/#markets) and look through the list of exchanges that support Stellar. Find an exchange that better suits your needs in terms of supported payment methods, language, KYC/AML requirements, and so on. For example, [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/) works great for most EU countries.

**Indirect exchange**

There are also a few large regional exchanges that don't support Stellar so far. If you are from US, [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/) is might be what you are looking for. Customers from Russia, Belarus, and Ukraine often prefer [Wex](https://wex.nz/) because it features Russian language interface and convenient fiat payment options. You can buy other crypto-currency, such as BTC or ETH, and then exchange it for XLM on the exchange listed on CoinMarketCap (see [Bittrex](https://bittrex.com) or [Binance](https://www.binance.com/)). For example, here is a [detailed guide](https://www.lumenauts.com/tutorials/how-to-buy-lumens-with-us-dollars) on how to convert fiat to XLM using GDAX + Bittrex.

> **TIP**: the minimum recommended amount to buy on the exchange is at least 5 XLM. You will be unable to create an account with amount less than 1 XLM. Each purchased asset requires 0.5 XLM base reserve. And don't forget about the fees. Yeah, they are almost neglectable (0.00001 XLM per operation); but we don't want to end with a situation when you lack only 0.00001 XLM to purchase a selected asset, right?

### 2. Exchange XLM for the asset of your choice

As soon as you get your XLM, you are ready to purchase any of the [hundreds](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset) of tokens freely traded on the Stellar Decentralized Exchange (also known as SDEX).

**Chose a wallet/trading client**

Choose one of the popular community-supported SDEX browser-based interfaces: [StellarTerm](https://stellarterm.com/), [InterStellar](https://interstellar.exchange/), or [StellarPort](https://stellarport.io/). Some [wallets](https://www.stellar.org/lumens/wallets/) also feature built-in exchange interface.

**Establish a trustline**

Before you can trade a Stellar-based asset, you'll need to establish a [trustline](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#trustlines).

> When you hold assets in Stellar, you’re actually holding credit from a particular issuer. The issuer has agreed that it will trade you its credit on the Stellar network for the corresponding asset–e.g., fiat currency, precious metal–outside of Stellar.
>
> When you hold an asset, you must trust the issuer to properly redeem its credit. Since users of Stellar will not want to trust just any issuer, accounts must explicitly trust an issuing account before they’re able to hold the issuer’s credit.
>
> To trust an issuing account, you create a **trustline**. Trustlines are entries that persist in the Stellar ledger. They track the limit for which your account trusts the issuing account and the amount of credit from the issuing account that your account currently holds.

All wallets and trading clients allow you to create a trustline specifying two required parameters: asset code and issuer address. Each trustline requires 0.5 XLM base reserve; those funds are "frozen" on your account. You will be able to reclaim the reserve when your remove the trustline.

**Buy an asset**

Navigate to active markets page, find the *{ASSET}-XLM* trading pair for the asset you'd like to purchase. Set the price (for small trades buying at the market price is recommended), buying amount, and submit your order.

Once the order is executed (approximately 4 seconds if you are buying at the market price), you'll get your assets.

**Congratulations! It was not so easy, but we did it!**